# Python парсинг xml: вытащить данные из ячеек вложенной таблицы

Tags: python, xml, beautiful-soup

Как с помощью bs4 получить такую структуру:

```
[[8], [9, 'Расчёт №1', '548100', 'Smr Hide'], [9,'Расчёт №2', '1192201', 'Smr Hide'], [10]]
```

из xml-файла с данными:

```
<AddZatrats>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="8"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="9">
  <AddZatr Caption="Расчет 1" Value="548100" Options="Smr Hide"/>
  <AddZatr Caption="Расчет 2" Value="1192201" Options="Smr Hide"/>
</AddZatrGlava>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="10"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="11"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="12"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="13"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="14"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="15"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip install lxml bs4`

```
src = """<AddZatrats>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="8"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="9">
  <AddZatr Caption="Расчет 1" Value="548100" Options="Smr Hide"/>
  <AddZatr Caption="Расчет 2" Value="1192201" Options="Smr Hide"/>
</AddZatrGlava>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="10"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="11"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="12"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="13"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="14"/>
<AddZatrGlava Glava="15"/>
"""
```

---

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup, Tag

soup = Soup(src, 'lxml')
def parse_part(tag: Tag):
    num, *_ = map(int, tag.attrs.values())
    
    has_parts = False  
    for elem in tag.select('addzatr'):
        has_parts = True
        yield [num] + [re.sub('(Расчет\s+)(?=\d+)', '\\1№', j) for j in elem.attrs.values()]
    
    if not has_parts:
        yield [num]

print(
    [item for i in soup.select('addzatrglava') for item in parse_part(i)]
)
```

---

```
[[8], [9, 'Расчет №1', '548100', 'Smr Hide'], [9, 'Расчет №2', '1192201', 'Smr Hide'], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15]]
```